# "object has no attribute 'configure'" - Label.Configure Only Works Once?

Tags: python-3.x, image, tkinter, configure

I am writing a little test program for TheMovieDB API. I display the movie poster image in a Label and everything works fine, however if I a try to change the image to another poster I get told "object has no attribute 'configure'" which seems strange as I used it previously with no error?

I create the label....

```
    self.posterImage = tk.Label(self.frameInfo, text="")
    self.posterImage.pack(side=tk.LEFT)
```

And I then load the image from a URL with...

```
     response = requests.get("http://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w185" + str(movie.poster_path))
     img_data = response.content
     image = Image.open(BytesIO(img_data))
     img = ImageTk.PhotoImage(image)
     self.posterImage.configure(image=img, text="")
     self.posterImage = img
```

The first time that I display the poster image, everything works fine. However, if I then want to display a different poster image after I have already display the first I get....

```
AttributeError: 'PhotoImage' object has no attribute 'configure'
```

Does anyone have any idea why please?

Thanks!

Comment: You replace the `tkLabel` with an `ImageTk.PhotoImage` - `self.postImage = img`.

Comment: @jonrsharpe : If I remove "self.posterImage.configure", the image is not displayed at all the first time. If I look at lots of tutorials on PhotoImage,  "self.posterImage = img" is the common way described to display the image. What should I do differently then?

Comment: `self.postImage = img` may be `self.postImage.image = img`.  It is used to keep a reference of `img`.  However, you can simply change `img` to instance variable instead, e.g. change all `img` to `self.img`.